# Date input is wider than text input when wrapped in .input-group in chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a horizontal form with two input fields: `type="text"` and `type="date"`. Both the fields are wrapped in `.input-group`. Also, I wrapped the input groups in in grid columns `.col-xs-4` to enforce desired widths. But the date field is wider than the text field and its column. Does anybody know how to make the date input the same width as parent column?

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qtdry2ru/14/)

It seems it's related to this issue https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=346051

Comment: I accidentally submitted that comment, Alexander - sorry about that, I clearly see the issue now - on Chrome there is placeholder text that makes it wider, correct?

Comment: Np. I'm not sure about the placeholder text. I think it happens because of `.input-group`.

Comment: Ok, because on my screen in the newest version of Chrome, I see that the `date` input is wider than the `text` because of the placeholder content ([mm/dd/yyyy](http://imgur.com/a/uogRN)) - also should note that this isn't technically a *"placeholder"* just the mechanisms associated with a date picker

Comment: I understand. I added one more date input and you can see that the placeholder doesn't impact on the width of input. Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qtdry2ru/14/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hack around this in `chrome` by using [`display: flex`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp) and overriding the default style rules for the bootstrap elements.

Be sure to check [support for flex here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) as it is not widely support as other `display` rules; although [bootstrap v4 will be utilizing it](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/flexbox/).

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/uaqs99fu/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Because minimal width of date is larger then your 4 coll (bacause of all that input stuff at the end like the arrows) it is larger then the normal input. make it col-xs-5 and it works

Comment: Ok. But why the minimal of date is larger? Try to remove `.input-group` and width of date will become the same width as `.col-xs-4`.

Comment: like i said it has a hidden minimum width after that it doesn't shrink anymore your text input doesn't have that so it is more flexible

Comment: Please, take a look at the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qtdry2ru/14/). There is one more date input which is shrinked.

Comment: But that is not in combination with input group so bootstrap has an other behavior for that. In the input group it seems to have this minimum width.

Comment: Definitely it behaves differently. Do you know how to turn off this minimum width?

Comment: not realy there is a trick to remove the input elements but i tryed that on your case and the x after you put something in makes it this big regardles